# How to access a variable from java objects in a java collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

I am using Mongo Java Driver, and I am trying to use filters on the `collection.find()` function. For example, when I have a key which is a java object, the class of which contains certain fields:

```
Document document = (Document) collection.find(and(
    eq("m_seniority", key.getM_seniority()),
    eq("m_currency",key.getM_currency()),
    eq("m_redCode",key.getM_redCode()),
    eq("m_companyId",key.getM_companyId())
)).first();
```

I use the above command. But when I want to do that in bulk, I am being passed a collection of keys, ( `Collection keys` ), I can't access particular variables of the java objects inside as below:

```
List<Document> docs =  (List<Document>) collection.find(and(
    eq("m_seniority", keys.getM_seniority()),
    eq("m_currency",keys.getM_currency()),
    eq("m_redCode",keys.getM_redCode()),
    eq("m_companyId",keys.getM_companyId())
)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Because getters are not of the collection, but just the objects, i can't use getters on the collection. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample document? And perhaps flesh out the code around the above blocks? Also, should "key" be "keys" in each of the `eq()` methods in the second code sample above? i.e. is the second block attempting to be a find call for any key in a given collection of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an `or` query on all of the `Collection keys`:

```
List<Bson> keyFilters = new ArrayList<>();
// for each key create an 'and' filter on seniority, currency, redcode and companyid
for (Key key : keys) {        
    keyFilters.add(
        Filters.and(eq("m_seniority", key.getM_seniority()),
            Filters.eq("m_currency",key.getM_currency()),
            Filters.eq("m_redCode",key.getM_redCode()),
            Filters.eq("m_companyId",key.getM_companyId())
        )
    );
}

List<Document> docs =  (List<Document>) collection.find(
        // 'or' all of the individual key filters
        Filters.or(keyFilters)
).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great answer. Just one question. When I am iterating on keys, it says Type mismatch between Object and Key, as shown in https://pasteboard.co/GY7tY9O.png . Can you help with that?

Comment: And I can't typecast because it needs an iterable type for iterating as shown in https://pasteboard.co/GY7At4Z.png

Comment: Okay I just added `Collection<CurveKeys>` (specifying the type in the generic Collection) and it works! Thanks a lot!